# R-ggplot2 geom_line() in R

Tags: r, visualization

```
WindSpeed9am    WindSpeed3pm
6               20
4               17
30              6
```

New to R language. I want to use geom_line for to compare both of these attributes. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

To use `geom_line`, you need at least two variables (for the x and y-axis). From context, I added a variable `day`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(day = row_number()) %>%                     # add second variable for x-axis
  pivot_longer(WindSpeed9am:WindSpeed3pm) %>%        # turn into a tidy/long format which ggplot expects
  ggplot(aes(x = day, y = value, colour = name)) +   # start the plot and set aesthetics
  geom_line()                                        # add lines
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

This is a rather basic question, so as an extra to the specific answer I suggest you learn more about `ggplot2` [from this book](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html)

## data

```
df <- read.table(text = "WindSpeed9am    WindSpeed3pm
6               20
4               17
30              6 ", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate for your time and help! Learned something now!

Comment: You're welcome! You can upvote and/or accept the answer to show it helped you ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Add id column for x axis with `row_number()`
2. bring data in long format with `pivot_longer`
3. use `ggplot` `colour` and `group` for `geom_line`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -id
  )
ggplot(df1, aes(factor(id), value, colour=name, group=name)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

data:

```
df <- tribble(
~WindSpeed9am,    ~WindSpeed3pm,
6,            20,
4,               17,
30,              6 )
```

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate for your answer! It works!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
WindSpeed9am <- c(6,4,30) 
WindSpeed3pm <- c(20,17,6)
df <- data.frame(WindSpeed9am,WindSpeed3pm)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df)+
  geom_line(aes(x=1:3,y=WindSpeed3pm),col="red")+
  geom_line(aes(x=1:3,y=WindSpeed9am),col="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate for your help! This work fine as well!